# Robust ng-if leave animation that doesn't recreate the element on cancel

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, ng-animate, gsap

I would like to have a `ng-if` javascript-based animation that animates elements leaving. However, if the boolean controlling `ng-if` changes back to `true` before the element has left the DOM, I would like for the existing element to be re-used, rather than a new one created.

The issue can be seen using a simple animation that doesn't actually do anything but take up time:

```
app.animation('.toggle', function($window) {
  return {
    leave: function(element, done) {
      $window.setTimeout(done, 2000);
    }
  };
});
```

with HTML like

```
<button ng-click="toggle = !toggle">Toggle me a lot!</button>
<p ng-if="toggle" class="toggle">Should only ever be one of these</p>
```

If you can the `ng-if` condition on an element with the class `toggle` multiple times in quick succession, then several of them end up in the DOM. Is it possible to only have at most one of them in the DOM at any one time?

My reason is that it feels more expected (at least for me) for the element that is already on screen to react to changes in state, from its current position in animation, rather than a new one created as though the previous one had fully disappeared. My actual use case is using Angular UI router views, where moving back/forwards between states causes the same template to be in the DOM multiple times, but I'm hoping that answers to this question may inspire solutions to the more complicated routing case.

I realise I can use ng-hide or ng-class, but I would like for the element to be removed from the DOM at the end of the animation. This would also (hopefully) make the answer to this question more similar to the UI routing case, as ui-view behaves more like ng-if in it is added/removed to the DOM on state change.

You can see the above example at http://plnkr.co/edit/hvEshhqOiC31q9wSjtL1?p=preview

Answer (score 2):

Try using ng-hide instead of ng-if. 
From: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf

> The ngIf directive removes or recreates a portion of the DOM tree based on an {expression}. If the expression assigned to ngIf evaluates to a false value then the element is removed from the DOM, otherwise a clone of the element is reinserted into the DOM.

So if you want to prevent DOM duplication use ng-hide as it will just set the display of the previously exisiting DOM element (your p tag) to display:none, when the value of the ng-hide is truthy.

in response to your edit:
Why not just only fire when not animating?
http://plnkr.co/edit/WqtjvytwEfOjhwvfhgvF?p=preview

```
app.animation('.toggle:not(.ng-animate)', function($window) {
return {
    leave: function(element, done) {
      $window.setTimeout(done, 2000);
    }
  };
});
```

Comment: This is an option, but I would like to know if there is a reasonable way to do with with the element not being in the DOM at the end of the transition. I have edited the question to make this clearer.

Comment: Then try passing in the current state of the item. For example if the user just clicked the toggle, set another variable say "active" to true, and set it false when the timeout is complete. Then, never call the setTimeout function when active is already true. Am I getting closer?

Comment: I'm not sure, I think some code might be needed to make it clearer. (If it's different enough from your answer above, then a second separate answer might be appropriate)

Comment: I don't think the `.animation` has any affect in your plunkr . The behaviour seems to be exactly the same as without the `.animation` http://plnkr.co/edit/lpSImQENgkrdaFD4lyMP?p=preview . Also, in your plunkr the element always disappears immediately in all cases that I tested, which isn't the behaviour that I'm after: there is to be a javascript animation on leave, (which in my simplified example is just a timeout)

Answer (score 1):

I hacked the source of `ng-if` to come up with a way of using a similar directive that

- Doesn't recreate the element if the leave animation is interrupted
- Doesn't destroy the scope on the leaving element until the animation has finished, so if the leaving is interrupted, all binding/events etc still work.

Below is the code for the directive, which I've called `animIf`. It isn't multi-element like `ngIf` and I strongly suspect there are cases where it's dodgy, as testing has been limited.

```
app.directive('animIf', function($animate) {
  return {
    transclude: 'element',
    priority: 600,
    terminal: true,
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function($scope, $element, $attr, ctrl, $transclude) {
      var latestValue, block, childScope, enterPromise, leavePromise;
      $scope.$watch($attr.animIf, function ngIfWatchAction(value) {
        latestValue = value;
        if (value) {
          if (leavePromise) {
            // Cancelling leaving animation
            // still removes the element from the DOM,
            // so we immediately put it back in
            $animate.cancel(leavePromise);
            leavePromise = null;
            enterPromise = $animate.enter(block.clone, $element.parent(), $element);
            enterPromise.then(function() {
              enterPromise = null;
            });
          } else if (!childScope) {
            // New clone to be created + injected
            $transclude(function(clone, newScope) {
              childScope = newScope;
              clone[clone.length++] = document.createComment(' end animIf: ' + $attr.animIf + ' ');
              block = {
                clone: clone
              };
              enterPromise = $animate.enter(clone, $element.parent(), $element);
              enterPromise.then(function() {
                enterPromise = null;
              });
            });
          }

        } else {
          if (enterPromise) {
            $animate.cancel(enterPromise);
            enterPromise = null;
          }
          if (block) {
            leavePromise = $animate.leave(block.clone);
            leavePromise.then(function() {
              leavePromise = null;

              if (!latestValue && childScope) {
                // Scope is only destroyed at the end of the animation
                // This is different to how ngIf works, where it is destroyed
                // at the beginning
                if (childScope) {
                  childScope.$destroy();
                  childScope = null;
                }
                block = null;
              }
            });
          }
        }
      });
    }
  };
});
```

To ensure that it actually makes a real animation possible, I've integrated with GSAP's TweenMax, for an animation that is different on enter to leave, but if it's interrupted, then it reverses to its original position.

```
app.animation('.toggle', function(TweenMax) {

  function reverseOrClear(element) {
    if (element[0]._toggleTween) {
      var tween = element[0]._toggleTween;
      tween.reversed(!tween.reversed());
    } else {
      element[0]._toggleTween = null;
    }  
  }

  function onComplete(element, done) {
     element[0]._toggleTween = null;
     done();    
  }

  return {
    enter: function(element, done) {
      function enterComplete() {
        onComplete(element, done);
      }
      // Not Using .data since data seems to be removed from element when
      // it is removed from the DOM     
      element[0]._toggleTween = element[0]._toggleTween
        || TweenMax.from(element, 1, {opacity: 0, y: 200, onComplete: enterComplete, onReverseComplete: enterComplete});

      return function() {
        reverseOrClear(element);
      };
    },
    leave: function(element, done) {
      function leaveComplete() {
        onComplete(element, done);
      }

      element[0]._toggleTween = element[0]._toggleTween
        || TweenMax.to(element, 1, {opacity: 0, y: -200, onComplete: leaveComplete, onReverseComplete: leaveComplete});

      return function() {
        reverseOrClear(element);
      };
    }
  };
});
```

This can be seen at http://plnkr.co/edit/ZkylJwkesu6sztin6ZDB?p=preview

I suspect in many cases it'll be nicer to have the same-but-reversed animation on enter and leave, but that would just be a special case of the above code.

Answer (score 0):

A way is to not integrate with ngAnimate at all, and just use a directive that handles both ngIf-style adding/removing from the DOM, and the animation. There is less code, it feels more flexible as you're not limited to what ngAnimate can do, and it's clearer as there are fewer moving parts.

Below is an example, integrated with GSAP

```
app.directive('animIf', function(TweenMax) {
  return {
    transclude: 'element',
    priority: 600,
    terminal: true,
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function($scope, $element, $attr, ctrl, $transclude) {
      var latestValue, latestClone, childScope, tween;
      var firstTime = true;

      function onEnterComplete() {
        tween = null;
      }

      function onLeaveComplete() {
        tween = null;
        if (!latestValue) {
          childScope.$destroy();
          childScope = null;
          latestClone.remove();
          latestClone = null;
        }
      }

      $scope.$watch($attr.animIf, function ngIfWatchAction(value) {
        latestValue = value;
        if (tween) {
          tween.reversed(!tween.reversed());
        } else if (value) {
          if (!childScope) {
            $transclude(function(clone, newScope) {
              latestClone = clone;
              childScope = newScope;
              $element.after(clone);

              // Just like ngAnimate, don't animate elements initially.
              // Could be configurable if needed
              if (!firstTime) {
                // Hard coded style for this example, but could get from attributes, style sheets...
                tween = TweenMax.from(latestClone, 1, {opacity: 0, y: 200, onComplete: onEnterComplete, onReverseComplete: onLeaveComplete});
              }    
            });
          }
        } else if (childScope) {
          tween = TweenMax.to(latestClone, 1, {opacity: 0, y: -200, onComplete: onLeaveComplete, onReverseComplete: onEnterComplete});
        }
        firstTime = false;
      });
    }
  };
});
```

This can be seen at http://plnkr.co/edit/IY2icRQt4dsmVVbsnduj?p=preview